# npm install results to error in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I am trying to make a container of node for my node app and followed the sample from Nodejs site [enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)
Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:argon

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp 
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
ADD . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But I get error in npm install

```
    npm info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm info using npm@2.15.1
    npm info using node@v4.4.4
    npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
    npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-23-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.4
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
    npm ERR! path /package.json
    npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall open

    npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open    '/package.json'
    npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm  itself.
    npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it..I had to change the dns in the docker configuration

Comment: how is that related?